# Problem with space distribution in nested flexbox and CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

My `aside` element and `div.content` should, as far as I know, take half of the available space in `div.container`. Also, the grid in `div.content` should take all available vertical space.

The problem is that grid items are unable to take any height (if not hard coded). Also, all of the vertical space that grid takes (because of `grid-gap`) is taken both from `aside` element and `div.content` which means that `div.content` steals `aside`'s vertical space and these two elements are no longer the same height.

Height of `aside` equals the height of `div.content` minus height of the grid.

In conclusion, height set for `div.content` by flexbox is prohibited to use. Child elements added to `div.content` behave more like its siblings.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #1A1C22;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #6C757D;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

section {
  background-color: #343A40;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container">
    <aside></aside>
    <div class="content">
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
      <section></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: you should consider `flex:1 1 0%` (the flex-basis:0%) and min-height:0 for content but still the same issue

Comment: ^ the above seems to work fine on Firefox but not Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just about get it to work both in Chrome & Firefox by *explicitly* specifying `height` instead of `flex-basis` and set `flex: 1 0 auto` to the `.container`. Also use `flex: 1` instead of `flex: 1 1 auto` for `content` and `aside` (sets `flex-basis: 0` instead of *auto*) - see demo below and a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/rp7xztun/2/):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #1A1C22;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  /* flex: 1 0 400px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 12px;
  height: 400px; /* added */
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* added */
}

aside {
  background-color: #6C757D;
  flex: 1; /* changed */
}

.content {
  flex: 1; /* changed */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

section {
  background-color: #343A40;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="container">
  <aside></aside>
  <div class="content">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

---

There are few problems with the above solution:

- it is not so intuitive that for *column flexboxes* height is specified for correct behaviour,
- note that still there is a 4px difference in height between the `aside` and `content` which is clearly the 2px border of the content.

---

#### Use CSS Grid for layouting

A grid layout solves these problems easily - flexboxes fare well as a 1-D solution but is not up to the mark in some layouts such as this. Here I'd remove the `container` wrapper and use a 4-row layout (`grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 1fr) 100px;`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(200px, 1fr) 100px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #6C757D;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.content section {
  background-color: #343A40;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #1A1C22;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<aside></aside>
<article class="content">
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: @biggerleb also upvote if the answer helped you, thank you :)